# How to find the modulo multiplicative inverse?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

"Find the multiplicative inverse $(\overline {47})^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{53}$"

My attempt so far is to use the Euclidean algorithm to establish that (-1/6)(47) + (1/6)(53) = 1

However I'm not exactly sure how this relates to the multiplicative inverse.

Would the multiplicative inverse simply be (-1/6)?

Comment: all the members of $\mathbb Z_{53}$ are also in $\mathbb Z, \frac 16$ is not in $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @DougM: Elements of $\Bbb Z_{53}$ are most assuredly *not* in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure they are.  Tell me one that isn't.

Comment: @DougM: You need to learn the definitions here. Elements of $\Bbb Z_{53}$ are *equivalence classes* of integers (i.e., each one is an infinite set), not integers.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the Euclidean correctly, you'll have two *integers* $a$ and $b$ so that
$$a\cdot 47 + b\cdot 53 =1.$$
What does this equation tell you if you interpret it mod $53$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  :) I was skipping steps as I worked backwards - I have now managed to get the integers a = -9 and b = 53. But I'm still a little unsure as to why -9 is the answer here...

Comment: Your numbers don't check. I suspect you meant something else for $b$. Mod $53$ we get $47a\equiv 1$, so  $\bar a$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\overline{47}$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake again! b = 8. I think I understand what you mean now... (47 x -9) = -423, and -423mod(53) = 1. Great, thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. But, better, mod 53 the 53 term totally disappears, so you don't need all that arithmetic!

Answer (score 0):

The identity element is $1$ because $(1\times a)\mod b=a$
A multiplication inverse is such that $(a\times a^{-1})\mod b=1$
For $47^{-1} $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_{53}$
i.e. We have to find the element a such that $47a=53b+1\implies a=\frac{53b+1}{47}$. Now the integer value of $b \mod{53}$ for which a is an integer is the answer.
That is what the euclidean algorithm suggests.

Answer (score 0):

the Euclidean gives $8\cdot53 - 9\cdot47 =1$, and thus considering the equality in $\mod 53$, and assuming the fact that $-9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{53}$ equals to $44$. We're done.